# Arraylist is of type LinkedTreeMap instead of Brewer

Tags: java, android, gson

I am trying to make my response class generic. The problem is that it returns a List with the type com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap instead of the type Brewer.

The function that starts all this:

```
List<Brewer> brewerList = null;
try {
    Response<Brewer> responseHandler = new Response<Brewer>();
    brewerList = responseHandler.getAll(response);
    functionCallBack = Constants.FUNCTION_DB_BREWER;
    list = brewerList.toArray(new Brewer[brewerList.size()]);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Tools.LOG_ERROR(e);
}
```

This is my response class:

```
public class Response<T> {

public List<T> getAll(JSONObject response) throws IOException {
    List<T> brewerList = null;

    // Map JSON to JAVA Objects
    Type listResponse = new TypeToken<ListResponse<T>>() {
    }.getType();
    ListResponse<T> responseObject = Shared.gson.fromJson(response.toString(), listResponse);

    if (responseObject != null) {
        // Status, Message, Data
        int status = responseObject.getStatus();

        Tools.LOG_DEBUG("Response - getAll, Status: " + status);

        if (responseObject.getData() != null && responseObject.getStatus() == 200) {
            brewerList = responseObject.getData();
        } else {
            Tools.LOG_DEBUG("Couldn't find the webservices!");
        }
    }
    return brewerList;
}
}
```

And this is my data class that i give to parse from json

```
public class ListResponse<T> {

private int status;
private List<T> data;

public ListResponse() {
}

public int getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(int status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public List<T> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<T> data) {
    this.data = data;
}
}
```

Exception:

```
04-11 10:54:55.994  31660-31660/be.appmax.ktsjjt E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: source[0] of type com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be stored in destination array of type be.appmax.ktsjjt.models.Brewer[]
        at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
        at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(ArrayList.java:523)
        at be.appmax.ktsjjt.database.SyncHandler.onRestTaskCompleted(SyncHandler.java:96)
        at be.appmax.ktsjjt.webservices.WSBrewer$1.onSuccess(WSBrewer.java:36)
        at com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler$1$1.run(JsonHttpResponseHandler.java:125)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Because you can't do that in Java due to type erasure. `T` isn't known.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do what you're trying to do because of type erasure in Java.

The `TypeToken` hack used by various libraries that do deserialization tries to get around this, but you can't use it with a generic type parameter as you're attempting to do. The type of `T` is erased at runtime and Gson can no longer determine the actual type so ... it returns a `Map`.

**Edit to add:** The way to get around this is to pass in the `TypeToken` rather than trying to create it in the method. This allows the type to be known. The tricky bit is in your case you want to return a `List<T>` but the `TypeToken` is actually `ListResponse<T>`. Because of that you have to get a bit creative with Generics and infer the TypeToken type with a bounding:

```
public <V extends ListResponse<T>> List<T> getAll(JSONObject response, TypeToken<V> token) throws IOException {
    ...
    V responseObject = 
        Shared.gson.fromJson(response.toString(), token.getType());
    ...
}
```

When you call this, you'll need to pass in the `TypeToken` instance, but then it will work.

```
Response<Brewer> responseHandler = new Response<Brewer>();
TypeToken<ListResponse<Brewer>> token = new TypeToken<ListResponse<Brewer>>(){};
brewerList = responseHandler.getAll(response, token);
```

Comment: Ow ok so there is no way around this?

Comment: @Ghost See the edit. You have to get a bit creative, but I think that will solve the issue.